# React with TypeScript: get props from generic array of objects using a key's type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define a generic component that gets passed a list of objects containing two keys: `component` & `props`. I'd like to infer the type of `props` using the passed component's type.

What I have so far is this:

```ts
import React from 'react';

type ComposableComponentDefinition<C extends React.ComponentType = React.ComponentType> = {
  component: C;
  props: React.ComponentProps<C>;
};

const Compose: React.FC<ComposeProps> = ({ children, components = [] }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {components.reduceRight((acc, c) => {
        const Component = typeof c === 'function' ? c : c.component;
        const props = (typeof c === 'object' && c.props) || {};
        return <Component {...props}>{acc}</Component>;
      }, children)}
    </>
  );
};

Compose.displayName = 'Compose';

export type ComposeProps = {
  components: ComposableComponentDefinition[];
};
export default Compose;
```

I use it as follows:

```ts
<Compose
  components={[
    { component: SomeComponent, props: {  } },
    { component: AnotherComponent, props: anotherComponentProps },
  ]}
>
```

Problem is, I can't have the TypeScript compiler provide me with props inference! Even if I believe it has all the information required to do so.

Has someone already stumbled upon that kind of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Can you be a little more specific about what your requirements are? What you you mean "I can't have the TypeScript compiler provide me with props inference"? Props inference where?

Comment: I want to make the compiler throw an error when I put something in `props: { <here> }` that is not in the component's own props. For example let's say I use Redux's `Provider`, if I put a `store` prop everything should be ok but not if I put a `toto` prop.